# Shouldn't the method explicitly contract with the signature of interface?

Tags: go

I am new with the golang, I am not quite understand why the below demo program could be executed successfully,

```
type fake interface {
    getAge(valueInt int,  valStr string) (age int, name string, err error)
}

type Foo struct {
    name string
}

func (b *Foo) getAge(valueInt int, valStr string) (age int, retErr error) {
    age = valueInt
    return age, nil
}
func main() {
    inst := &Foo{name:"foo"}
    value, _ := inst.getAge(2, "foo")
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

The interface wants to return three value, but the method `getAge` only return two, but it still works. How to understand this behavior in golang?

Thanks!

Comment: You’ve declared an interface that you’re not using. What do expect to happen?

Comment: You not use interface fake now. Used func (b *FOO) getAge is not getAge of interface.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo` doesn't implement `fake`. This is apparent if you extend your code sample a bit ([try it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VPNMNcoFnU5)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type fake interface {
    getAge(valueInt int, valStr string) (age int, name string, err error)
}

type Foo struct {
    name string
}

func (b *Foo) getAge(valueInt int, valStr string) (age int, retErr error) {
    age = valueInt
    return age, nil
}


func bar(f fake) {
  _, name, _ := f.getAge(10, "")
}

func main() {
    inst := &Foo{name: "foo"}
    value, _ := inst.getAge(2, "foo")
    fmt.Println(value)

    bar(inst)
}
```

This produces a compile error that's pretty descriptive:

```
prog.go:28:5: cannot use inst (type *Foo) as type fake in argument to bar:
    *Foo does not implement fake (wrong type for getAge method)
        have getAge(int, string) (int, error)
        want getAge(int, string) (int, string, error)
```